# In Ansible, how do I execute a command via Git-bash window?

Tags: ansible

Ansible v2.11, Windows 2019 target

I want to execute a command in a Git-bash window, like this, where `<some_command` can be anything I want to execute, e.g., `ls` or `pwd` for argument's sake.

```
- block:
  - name: Check if git-bash exists
    win_stat:
      path: 'c:\Program Files\Git\git-bash.exe'
    register: git_bash_st
  - name: Ensure that git-bash exists
    assert:
      that:
      - git_bash_st.stat.exists
  - name: "Check if {{ yesterdays_files }} exists"
    win_stat:
      path: "{{ yesterdays_files }}"
    register: yester_st
  - name: "Execute a command in the git-bash shell"
    win_command: "git-bash.exe ls {{ yesterdays_files }}"
    args:
      chdir: "C:\\Program Files\\Git"
    when: yester_st.stat.exists
```

However, the task just hangs and doesn't proceed. Any clues?

Answer (score 0):

You could try the win_shell module with an extra arg ˋexecutable='c:\Program Files\Git\git-bash.exe'ˋ . You have used an extra arg ˋchdirˋ allready.

I do not know git-bash at all, but the command for git-bash might be only ˋls blaaˋ then.

Comment: I tried this and this hangs the same way as my task. Thanks